# Problema en ciclo for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

`leaderboard.length` esta definido desde el servidor y en mi caso es 12

```
var l = leaderboard.length;
var i = 0;

for ( ; i < l; i++) {   
    var o = (i + 1) + ". " + name;
}
```

Esto me mostrará la posicion de los jugadores del 1 al 11

Pero mi problema es que aunque `leaderboard.length` sea 11, quiero que muestre todas las posiciones, pero a la posición 9 no le muestre el numero 9 o sea solo:

1 - Jugador 1 
2 - Jugador 2 
3- Jugador 3 
4- Jugador 4 
5- Jugador 5  
6- Jugador 6 
7- Jugador 7
8- Jugador 8
***- Jugador 9*** 
10 - Jugador 10
11 - Jugador 11

Comment: Ten en cuenta que estas evaluando a partir de 0 lo que quiere decir que los resultados estarán en el rango de 0~11 < 12 por lo que desplegaran los valores del 1 al 12.

Comment: fwBasic , te equivocas cuando i = 12 , no se mostrara el valor de 12 ya que se evaluara como falso

Comment: Resulta que i nunca llegara a ser 12 pues estas evaluando de 0 a 11 (equivale a 12 interacciones), es por ello que cuando despliegas el valor al sumarle 1 ( i + 1 ) el resultado estara en el rango de 1 a 12, te he dejados un ejemplo del resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O podrias usar un `IF`

```
var l = leaderboard.length;
var i = 0;

for ( ; i < l; i++) {

 if(i==8){
 var o = ". " + name;
 }else{
 var o = (i + 1) + ". " + name;
 }
```

Comment: muchas gracias , que pavada he preguntado , pero bueno soy novato :)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el operador ternario `A ? B : C`

```
l = leaderboard.length;
i = 0;

for( ; i < l; i++ ) {

  o = ( i == 8 ) ? ( name ) : ( (i + 1) + ". " + name );
}
```

Dicho operador *evalua* `A` y, si es `true`, devuelve `B`. En caso contrario, devuelve `C`.

Comment: Gracias , tambien me ha servido:)

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te ha servido de más utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que estas evaluando a partir de 0 lo que quiere decir que los resultados estarán en el rango de 0~11 < 12 por lo que se desplegaran los valores del 1 al 12, te dejo el resultado en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var l = 12;//leaderboard.length;
var i = 0;
var name = "Jugador n";

for ( ; i < l; i++) {   
    var o = (i + 1) + ". " + name;
    console.log(o);
}
```

lo correcto seria:

```js
var leaderboard="123456789012";
var name = "Jugador n";

for (i = 1; i < leaderboard.length; i++) {
 var o = (i==9) ? name : i+". "+name;
 console.log(o);
}
```

Comment: Ah claro te referias a i + 1 , gracias :)